# Set and manage editable UITextview in the custom shape

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

Currently, I am working on an iOS application, in which, our client asked for a feature and I am not quite sure how to implement it. We need to add an editable UITextView in the shape of specific map as attached in the image. While doing R&D I came to know that we can create a UITextView with the help of customized NSLayoutManager, NSTextStorage and NSTextContainer. But didn't get any detailed example for this type of complex issue.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank You!

Required editable textview within the customized shape.
[image]

Need to display text within the customized shape.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I'd create 4 `UITextFields` and handle the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` delegate on them. Then I'd combine the text of all 4 fields to one and split it manually according to its size.